# How to make WCF work in both http and https after upgrading .net to 4.5.2 from 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have spent weeks trying to figure out why upgrading .NET 4.0 to 4.5.2 has made my WCF services return a 404 when accessed via https, but not http. Before the upgrade it worked via both http and https.

This is a ASP.NET Website (Not Web Application)

Here is the Services.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" 
Debug="true" 
Service="Services" 
CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WCF_Services.vb" 
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Here is the web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>     
    <services>
      <service name="Services">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
            contract="IServices" behaviorConfiguration="EdpHelpBehavior" />
  </service> 
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EdpHelpBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior> 
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" 
        aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  />
```

Comment: Are you using the right port number for HTTPS?

Comment: I didnt know I could set that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a production server and a development server. I tried hours and hours of changes to the web.config file as well as some changes to IIS and asp_reg command in the cmd window. It wasn't until I added a ssl cert to the development domain that it started working. The production server already had this so I didn't think this was the cause. It was a combination of the web.config changes plus adding the cert that fixed it. After we got that we copied the webconfig to the production site with success.

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />


  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="ServiceModel" />
    <add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
  </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" /> 
 </system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors> 
</behaviors>    
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested using binding configuration ?

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSec">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Yes I tried it. It still returns a 404 for https, but causes http to fail.

Comment: Your endpoint have no address so have you 2 base addresses (http and https) and 2 endpoints (only one using security mode)

Comment: Hmm if your iis accept anonymous authentication you can try <security mode = "Transport" >
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
</security>

Comment: have you  also added certificate to the site ? and correctly configure iis to ssl ?